# React Login & Signup Form ant design onFinish not triggering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, antd

Okay so I have Login.js & Signup.js components
on the Login component, the onFinish event works perfectly
where as on Signup the onFinish doesn't work at at all
-- even not a console.log()

Login.js (username, password):

```
import React from 'react';
import { LockTwoTone,UserOutlined,LoadingOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Form, Input, Button, Spin } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
const antIcon = <LoadingOutlined type="loading" style={{ fontSize: 24 }} spin />;


class NormalLoginForm extends React.Component {
handleSubmit = (e) => {
console.log("i am getting printed");    
}
render() {
let errorMessage = null;
if (this.props.error) {
    errorMessage = (
        <p>{this.props.error.message}</p>
    );
}
return (
    <div>
        {errorMessage}
        {
            this.props.loading ?

            <Spin indicator={antIcon} />

            :

            <Form onFinish={this.handleSubmit} className="login-form col-xs-8">
                <FormItem name="username" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Username!' }]}>
                <Input prefix={<UserOutlined type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem name="password" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!' }]}>
                <Input prefix={<LockTwoTone  type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </FormItem>
                <FormItem>
                  <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
                      Login
                  </Button>
                </FormItem>
            </Form>
        }
  </div>
  );
 }
} 
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
    loading: state.loading,
    error: state.error
}
}
 const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    onAuth: (username, password) => 
 dispatch(actions.authLogin(username, password)) 
    }
}
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(NormalLoginForm);
```

SignUp.js (username, email, password, confirm-password):

```
import React from 'react';
import { MailTwoTone,LockTwoTone,UserOutlined,LoadingOutlined } from 
'@ant-design/icons';
import { Form, Input, Button } from 'antd';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import * as actions from '../store/actions/auth';

const FormItem = Form.Item;
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    };
  handleSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log("doesnt print me");
 }
  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
     const value = e.target.value;
     this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || 
 !!value });
  }
  validateToNextPassword = (values, pass,item3) => {
     return true; // for simplicity
  }
  render() {    
   return (
<div>

  <Form onFinish={this.handleSubmit} className="sign-up-form">
    
    <FormItem name="username" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input your Username!' }]}>            
            <Input prefix={<UserOutlined type="user" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Username" />            
    </FormItem>
    
    <FormItem name="email" rules={[{
      type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
     }, {
      required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
     }]}>          
        <Input prefix={<MailTwoTone type="mail" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} placeholder="Email" />          
    </FormItem>

    <FormItem name="password" rules={[{
      required: true, message: 'Please input your Password!',
    },{
      validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
    }]}>          
        <Input prefix={<LockTwoTone type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Password" />          
    </FormItem>

    <FormItem name="confirm" rules={[ {
      required: true, message: 'Please confirm your password!',
    },({ getFieldValue }) => ({
      validator(rule, value) {
        if (!value || getFieldValue('password') === value) {
          return Promise.resolve();
        }
        return Promise.reject('password does not match!');
      },
    }),
  ]}>          
        <Input prefix={<LockTwoTone type="lock" style={{ color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.25)' }} />} type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onBlur={this.handleConfirmBlur} />        
    </FormItem>

    <FormItem>
      <Button  type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{marginRight: '10px'}}>
          Sign Up
      </Button>
    </FormItem>

  </Form>
</div>
);
}
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        loading: state.loading,
        error: state.error
    }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
    onAuth: (username, email, password1, password2) => 
dispatch(actions.authSignup(username, email, password1, password2)) 
}
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) 
(RegistrationForm);
```

It is pretty much the same form that triggers the same function but it doesn't work on Signup.js
I checked everything possible... what could be the reason?

Comment: It would be nice if you post the whole code of both components

Comment: hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `validator` you are setting in the `rules` for the 'password' field is expecting to receive a function that returns a `Promise` but you are returning a boolean `true`. Your function `validateToNextPassword` should return a `Promise.resolve()` as a boolean function would return `true` or `Promise.reject()` as a `false`. Something like this:

```
    validateToNextPassword = (values, pass,item3) => {
         if (passesCondition)
           return Promise.resolve();
         else
           return Promise.reject('Error message');
    }
```

For a full example: https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register

Comment: Probably this could be a wrong place, but still i wanted to try for an answer for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66354698/form-onfinish-onsubmit-not-triggered-in-antd

Comment: Feel free to add another answer :)