# Form onFinish/onSubmit not triggered in AntD

Tags: reactjs, typescript, forms, validation, antd

**Simple demo of antd form onSubmit is not working**

https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-register

The onChange of field components are validated, but onFinish is not called on click of submit.

Is it because of lodash/webpack or react version dependency issue.

This is happening on lens electronjs application and the dependencies are below:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@k8slens/extensions": "4.0.0-beta.3",
    "antd": "4.8.4",
    "dayjs": "1.10.4",
    "k8s-api": "1.2.19",
    "lodash": "4.17.20",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-jsonschema-form": "1.8.1",
    "react-router": "5.2.0",
    "rjsf-antd": "0.1.5-alpha.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ant-design/compatible": "1.0.8",
    "@ant-design/icons": "4.5.0",
    "@rjsf/antd": "2.3.0",
    "@rjsf/core": "2.4.2",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.108",
    "@types/node": "12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "16.9.35",
    "@types/react-jsonschema-form": "1.7.4",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@types/redux": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "css-loader": "5.0.1",
    "husky": "4.3.7",
    "prettier": "2.1.1",
    "pretty-quick": "3.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
    "redux-observable": "^1.2.0",
    "sass": "1.32.0",
    "sass-loader": "10.0.2",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "stylelint": "12.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "8.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "19.0.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "3.13.0",
    "ts-loader": "8.0.4",
    "tslint": "5.20.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "1.18.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "4.1.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.6.0",
    "tslint-no-circular-imports": "0.3.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "2.0.1",
    "tslint-react": "3.2.0",
    "tslint-react-hooks": "2.2.1",
    "tslint-staged": "0.1.3",
    "typescript": "4.0.3",
    "webpack": "4.44.2",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.11"
  },
```

I don't see any console errors as well and the onFinish function is not at all called to post some messages.

Comment: Can you state the reason for downvote and close this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure for what reason, the submit button inside form not triggered. Hence handled with external submit validation function.

```
const handleFormSubmit = () => {
    console.log('called...');
    form
      .validateFields()
      .then((values) => {
        console.log('values ...', values);
        // Submit values
        // SubmitValues(values);
      })
      .catch((errorInfo) => {
        console.log('errorInfo ...', errorInfo);
      });
  };

        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" onClick={handleFormSubmit}>
          Log in
        </Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check if you have set up any custom validator for non-required input field. I had a similar issue where I forgot to let the custom validator return a resolved promise when there is no input (as it's not a required input field).

It's the line `else return Promise.resolve()` below fixed my issue.

```
  <Form.Item
    label="End Date"
    name="end_date"
    rules={[
      ({ getFieldValue }) => ({
        validator(_, value) {
          if (value) {
            if (value >= getFieldValue("start_date")) {
              return Promise.resolve()
            }
            return Promise.reject(
              "End date shall be later than the start date"
            )
          } else return Promise.resolve()
        },
      }),
    ]}
  >
```

Comment: Another similar issueI found is when you need to validate `fieldB` based on inputs of `fieldA`. The rules on `fieldA` will be triggered when you change `fieldA` but the warning wont' go away till you touch `fieldA` again. To fix this, just add a ` form.validateFields('fieldA')` to the `onChange` of `fieldB`